# Elegant way to check if multiple variables are bigger than 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have multiple variables in Python 3, that are assigned with 0 later they will get new different values from SQL Queries. I want to check if all of this variables are bigger than 0. My code

```
var1 = 0
var2 = 0
var3 = 0
...
...
if (var1 > 0 and var2 > 0 and var3 > 0 ):
     do something
```

is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Use an array and use `all(i > 0 for i in arr)`

Comment: Why the numbered variables? Just put those in a list and use `if all(variables):`.

Comment: ^This won't work for potentially negative variables

Comment: @christian Since when is `-1 > 0`?

Comment: @ChristianDean That is not the intended behavior: -1 is not greater than 0 (which is in OP)

Comment: If you're using numpy you could put all vars in an `np.array()` and check by `all(variables > 0)`.

Comment: @tsabsch or better `(variables > 0).all()`, which is faster.

Comment: `all([var1 > 0, var2 > 0, var3 > 0])`.

Comment: `min(variables) > 0`

Comment: @StefanPochmann that will not short circuit, unlike `all(var > 0 for var in variables)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're in a list (e.g. called `vars`), you can use the `all` function:

```
if all([v > 0 for v in vars]):
    do something
```

EDIT: @EliKorvigo made a good point about not needing to allocate the space for a list. You could just do this instead:

```
if all(v > 0 for v in vars):
    do something
```

which works equivalently to the first code block, but without allocating the list

Comment: There is no need to allocate memory for a list. Just use a generator expression, which fully utilizes `all`'s short circuiting behaviour.

Comment: Also, be careful. `vars` is the name of a built-in function. It'd be safer to avoid overwriting the built-in name and use something like `sql_vars` instead.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Thanks for that, I forgot you could use the generator expression directly in the `all` function